# Allow only Select and Copy from UITextField not working

Tags: ios, swift

I would like my UITextField to only allow select, copy and share. Here is what is have so far.

```
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    print("\(action.description) returns \(action == #selector(copy(_:)) || action == #selector(selectAll(_:)) || action == Selector(("_share:")) )" )
    
    return action == #selector(copy(_:)) || action == #selector(selectAll(_:)) || action == Selector(("_share:"))
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. When i do a long press or double tap, i get the following options:

```
 copy, select, select all, paste, share
```

print output

> cut: returns false
>
> copy: returns true
>
> delete: returns false
>
> _promptForReplace: returns false
>
> _transliterateChinese: returns false
>
> _insertDrawing: returns false
>
> _showTextStyleOptions: returns false
>
> _lookup: returns false
>
> _define: returns false
>
> _addShortcut: returns false
>
> _accessibilitySpeak: returns false
>
> _accessibilitySpeakLanguageSelection: returns false
>
> _accessibilityPauseSpeaking: returns false
>
> _share: returns true
>
> makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft: returns false
>
> makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight: returns false

How do i get rid of `paste` and `select`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're never allowing input, it sounds like you should really be using a `UILabel` and add tap/long-press gestures with only the actions you want available.

However if you still want to do it...

To effect Pasting, you'll need to subclass `UITextField` and override
[UIPasteConfigurationSupporting](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteconfigurationsupporting)'s functions e.g.

```
class UnpasteableTextField: UITextField {

    override func canPaste(_ itemProviders: [NSItemProvider]) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

As far as selection, you'll probably have to override something from [UITextInput](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput) or [UIResponderStandardEditActions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponderstandardeditactions).